# ERROR 1064 (4200): You have an error in SQL syntax - в чем ошибка?

Tags: email, сервер, centos, mysql

Здравствуйте  хотелось бы узнать у знающих людей, в чем и где кроется ошибка в синтаксисе:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO 'transport' ('domain', 'transport') VALUES (‘localhost.localdomain’, ‘virtual:’);
```

Вылетает ошибка такого содержания:

> ERROR 1064 (4200): You have an error in SQL syntax; check ... **for the right syntax to use near**  'transport' (... все тоже... )'; at line 1.

ОС CentOS 6.3-64 , mysql-5.1.61-4; это  фрагмент из базы данных для почты Postfix & Courier-Imap.

Comment: А если  'transport' без кавычек?

Comment: Должно быть:mysql> INSERT INTO `transport` (`domain`,`transport`) VALUES ('localhost.localdomain','virtual:')просто по Вашей записи не понятно что за кавычки.И еще, могу ошибаться, но возможно ; не нужна в конце.

Comment: в комментарии "съело" кавычки (те которые над Ё). INSERT INTO transport (domain,transport)

Answer (score 1):

чехарда с кавычками. вокруг строк должны быть или одинарные `'` или двойные `"` кавычки, вокруг идентификаторов кавычки в данном случае вообще не нужны, но если уж их использовать, то это должны быть «обратные» кавычки:

```
`
```

в приведённом примере можно написать так:

```
INSERT INTO transport (domain, transport)
VALUES ('localhost.localdomain', 'virtual:');
```